# How to avoid temp objects when returning NSString under ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

I've got a class with two properties:

```
@interface Contact : NSObject {
    NSString *lastname;
    NSString *lastNameUpper;
}
```

I've declared lastname as a property (and synthesize it in the .m-file):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastname;
```

However, I want to write my own method to access the lastNameUpper, so I declared a method:

```
- (NSString *) lastNameUpper;
```

and implemented it like this:

```
- (NSString *) lastNameUpper {
    if (!lastNameUpper) {
        lastNameUpper = [lastname uppercaseString];
    }
    return lastNameUpper;
}
```

This works all right, but as this is called quite often, a lot of temporary objects are called. Interestingly, the Instruments show a lot of "Malloc (4k)", and the number increase each time `lastNameUpper` is accessed. I can also see that the memory is allocated in `objc_retailAutoreleaseReturnValue`.

As this was working fine before I converted my project to ARC, I'm assuming that I have to make some ARC specific additions to the method signature, but I can't seem to be able to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code (except you should possibly make the properties `copy`, and set the uppercase string when the last name string is set). What temporary objects are you talking about? What actual problems is it causing?

Comment: @jrturton Updated the question with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `- (void)setLastname:(NSString*)aLastname` method (created automatically by `@synthesize lastname`, and set lastNameUpper as in the existing method.

Now create a lastNameUpper property (and synthesize it):

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *lastNameUpper;
```

Since this will return the pointer of the lastNameUpper instance variable, no copies should be made whenever this is accessed.

Comment: This seems to work (I'm running some more tests to confirm). Can anybody properly explain the behavior?

Comment: Not sure how ARC defines functions treated as properties (calling `obj.methodName` when no `@property` is defined), but possibly it checks if the returned object conforms to the NSCopying protocol and implements as copy. By specifying a `@property` and implementing the getter, it now knows how to implement specifically.

Answer (score 2):

0: you should *copy* your NSString properties:

```
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * lastname;
```

> I'm guessing that returning the string is implemented by copying it.

nope. copy of an *immutable* string is a retain operation. just run it in the profiler to see how much this costs in time and memory. also, there's no implicit copy in this case.

**Update**

I tested this on Lion-64. `uppercaseString` may return a *mutable* string.

To be safe, you may consider assigning a copy of the result of `uppercaseString`: `lastNameUpper = [[lastname uppercaseString] copy];`. that may result in more or less allocations, depending on how you used the string in your implementation. if your properties copy, then a copy will be made each time you assign it. the easy generalization is to assign a copy, and the rest usually takes care of itself.

**Test Program**

```
// ARC enabled
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Contact : NSObject
{
    NSString * lastname;
    NSString * lastNameUpper;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastname;

@end

@implementation Contact

@synthesize lastname;

- (NSString *) lastNameUpper {
    if (!lastNameUpper) {
        lastNameUpper = [lastname uppercaseString];
    }
    return lastNameUpper;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int n = 0;
        while (n++ < 100000) {
            Contact * c = [Contact new];
            c.lastname = @"skjdhskjdhaksjhadi";
            NSString * lastNameUpper = c.lastNameUpper;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Justin: I changed my code, but the behavior is still the same. I've updated my question as I can now see that no temporary strings are created, just a big malloc.

Comment: Whether `lastname` is copied or not is irrelevant to the question. The problem arises when accessing `lastNameUpper`, which is not defined as a read-only property.

Comment: @Thorsten updated - can you post your test for this? i'm wondering if you're just adding the same objects to an autorelease pool over and over again… in that case, the pool would just predictably grow and grow unless drained occasionally. if you are creating new objects and draining, then you would see much different results.

Comment: @Justin: Even when adding the copy in my method (either after the uppercaseString and/or in the return statement), I cannot see any changes.

Comment: Here's how I'm "testing": I'm running my app using the instrument for  allocations. There I can see a lot of memory being allocated (just 4k blocks of memory using malloc) and using the "Call Trees" I can see where the memory is allocated. It's in the method I mentioned, and it's either in a objc_autorelease or in a objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue system call. I'm not sure what is going on ...

Comment: @Thorsten in my test, copying the result of `uppercaseString` added allocations. however, i didn't see significant growth you see. i'll post mine.

Comment: `uppercaseString' by itself will add allocations, of course (unless the string was already in uppercase) - there is a new NSString with a different value. The scenario that I'm using is contributing to the significant increase I was seeing .. basically I'm comparing 3.000 contacts to look for duplicates - so lastnameUpper would be called roughly 9 million times ...

Comment: @Justin: One more difference to what I'm doing: You're creating a new contact each time .. please try what happens when you create the contact before the loop (so there is absolutely no necessity for creating/releasing new NSStrings).

Comment: yes. `uppercaseString` accounts for 66% of the total allocations in the test i posted. with 9 million comparisons, and substantial growth in that region, your program is likely just growing the current autorelease pool. if Leo's nonretained suggestion worked, then it is likely just autorelease pool growth from the sounds of it. you can either create autorelease pools explicitly (e.g. every 3000 compares), or even better, just initialize by copy an idempotent instance -- `- (id)initWithLastName:(NSString *)pLastName`… which then copies in initialization, has no setter, does not need autorelease

Comment: @Thorsten perhaps you should post your full program that exhibits this problem? i just tried this with 100000 elements, and it plateaued at 59 MB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10334/discussion-between-thorsten-and-justin)

Comment: Sorry I can't accept two answers .. Justin and I discussed this a bit further, and he was really helpful in pinning things down.